# Detect if the function is template or not

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a class with one member function and one template function with the same name:

```
struct S {
void f(int) {} // non-template

template <class T>
void f(T) {}   // template
};
```

Is there a way to detect on compile time that call of `f(int)` would be a normal member function, not a template function? Something like this `is_template_v<S::f(int)> == false`.

In case of absence regular member function `void f(int)` the check above should return `true`.

I'm looking for an answer based on c++17, but solution on more recent standard would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Just curious: What's your use case?

Comment: You might check that `&S::f<int>` exist...

Comment: Do you want to know which function is selected by overload resolution?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have a macro that generate a bunch of templated functions based on non-templated one. I would like to get compile time error when macro is added, but no regular function provided.

Comment: `CRTP` might be a better option than MACRO.

Comment: @Jarod42 even in case of existence non-template `f(int)` templated `S::f<int>` can be called.

Comment: @Jarod42 it's a legacy code, so I can't easily eliminate macros.

Comment: Can you write a macro that generates both the base function and the template? Then you could have a git hook to verify if only the macro generating both is used and never the one that generates only templates.

Comment: `is_template_v<S::f(int)> == false` is not possible, but underlying problem *might* be solved/worked-around if we better understand the context, real needs.

Comment: C++ simply doesn't work this way, on a fundamental level. There's nothing in C++ that will indicate if an expression resolves to an ordinary function call, after any overload resolution, or a template instantiation with deduced parameters.

Comment: *"I would like to get compile time error when macro is added, but no regular function provided."* - I assume that this macro somehow uses this regular function so you should probably already get a compile-time error. ¿Or maybe not? ¿What kind of macro it is? This question with this vague macro stuff looks like an XY problem.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ SYou mean you can't make a new function instead of the macro? You don't have to replace all the code using the macro in one release. Another option is to replace the macro with actual code generation, and get rid of all kinds of nasty C++ hackery

Comment: W.E.Brown about [template functions](https://youtu.be/NIDEjY5ywqU?t=203).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Something like this `is_template_v<S::f(int)> == false`

This is not exactly that, but rather *something like* that, used as  `is_template_f_int_v<S>`:

```cpp
template <class T>
struct is_template_f_int {
    static constexpr bool value =
        static_cast<void (T::*)(int)>(&T::template f<int>) ==
        static_cast<void (T::*)(int)>(&T::f);
};

template <class T>
inline constexpr bool is_template_f_int_v = is_template_f_int<T>::value;
```

That is, check if the two function pointers point at the same function.

You could also make a macro to make it a little more generic:

```cpp
#define IS_TEMPLATE(C, F, R, ...)                                       \
    (static_cast<R (C::*)(__VA_ARGS__)>(&C::template F<__VA_ARGS__>) == \
     static_cast<R (C::*)(__VA_ARGS__)>(&C::F))
```

Use like so:

```cpp
IS_TEMPLATE(S,f,void,int)
```

A version that does not require a function template to exist:

```cpp
template <class T>
struct is_template_f_int {
    static std::false_type test(...);

    template <class U>
    static auto test(U) -> std::bool_constant<
        static_cast<void (U::*)(int)>(&U::template f<int>) ==
        static_cast<void (U::*)(int)>(&U::f)>;

    static constexpr bool value = decltype(test(std::declval<T>()))::value;
};
```

```cpp
struct A {};
struct B {
    void f(int) {}
};
struct C {
    template <class T> void f(T) {}
};
struct D {
    void f(int) {}
    template <class T> void f(T) {}
};

int main() {
    std::cout << is_template_f_int_v<A> << '\n'  // false
              << is_template_f_int_v<B> << '\n'  // false
              << is_template_f_int_v<C> << '\n'  // true
              << is_template_f_int_v<D> << '\n'; // false
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an idea, looks like it could be improved to take into account possible cv-ref specifiers for member function. Generally I need to check if there a specific non-template member function amongst other overloaded template functions. I.e. same name, but potentially any number/types of arguments (variadic templates) and return types.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ This idea of a generalized version looks like an exercise you could practice with what I provided in the answer as inspriration. If you can't make it work, you could ask a new question and  specify the problem in such a way that the answer you got to your current question doesn't cut it.